# Definition of separable algebras over a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory, definition

Let $k$ be a field, and $A$ a commutative $k$-algebra. I noticed two definitions of what it means for $A$ to be separable over $k$:

**Definition 1 [Matsumura, Commutative Algebra, 1980, (27.D) + (27.G)]:** $A$ is *separable* over $k$ if for all field extensions $L$ of $k$, $A \otimes_k L$ is reduced.

**Definition 2 [https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/separable+algebra ]:** $A$ is *separable* over $k$ if for all field extensions $L$ of $k$, $A \otimes_k L$ has zero Jacobson radical.

Note that Definition 2 $\Rightarrow$ Definition 1 since the nilradical of a ring is contained in the Jacobson radical, but I don't see why Definition 1 $\Rightarrow$ Definition 2, unless some restrictions are imposed on $A$ (for e.g. if $A$ is of finite type over $k$, or if $A$ is generated as a $k$-algebra by a set $\{x_i\}_{i \in I}$  such that the cardinality of $I$ is less than the cardinality of $k$ [Stacks, Tag 00FU]).

**Question:** Are the two definitions equivalent? If not, is one definition better than the other for **commutative rings**?

Answer (score 4):

The definitions are not equivalent on the class of all commutative $k$-algebras.  Take $k = \mathbb{C}$ and $A = \mathbb{C}[[t]]$.  Since $A$ is a local PID 
with maximal ideal $(t)$, its Jacobson radical is thus $(t) \neq (0)$. On the other hand, for any perfect field $k$, if $A$ and $B$ are two reduced, commutative $k$-algebras, then $A \otimes_k B$ is also reduced (e.g. [see here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9436/reduced-%E2%8A%97-reduced-reduced-what-about-connected) for references to this standard-but-not-so-easy fact).

In my own experience, Definition 1 -- i.e., universally reduced -- is more standard than Definition 2 -- i.e., universally semiprimitive.  However, it should be mentioned that in many contexts, the separable algebras one is interested in are finite-dimensional over $k$.  (Indeed, sometimes this finite-dimensionality is taken as part of the definition.)  As you already know, in that case the two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for the simple example! I overlooked the fact that Definition (1) implies $A$ is reduced and Definition (2) implies $A$ has trivial Jacobson radical. Then it would have been clear that Definition 1 cannot imply 2 using [Matsumura, 1980, (27.E) Corollary] which says that an algebra over a perfect field is separable in the sense of Definition 1 if and only if it is reduced.

I always thought separatedness reflects reduced behavior, so I am glad to know that Definition 1 is more standard. But [Milne, Étale Cohomology, Pg 20] uses Definition 2, so I asked.

Comment: But  just as you point out, Milne uses Definition 2 mostly for finite $k$-algebras where the two definitions coincide. So no harm done.